# Load code lines for a robot-file

Tags: testing, refactoring, robotframework

I have huge robot-files. In all this files a section of the code is the same. Because of DRY I want to shorten the files and put the code to an other file. How to call this 100 robot-code lines from an other file then?

file1.robot

```
MyTest1
    <Content of other file>
    Some other keywords
```

file2.robot

```
MyTest2
    <Content of other file>
    Some other keywords
```

Other file

```
Log to console    1
Log to console    2
Log to console    3
Log to console    .
Log to console    .
Log to console    100
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The way to do this is to use keywords in a [resource file](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#resource-files). You can't include raw lines of code.

For example:

### other.robot

```
*** Keywords ***
Do something
    log to console   1
    log to console   2
    ...
```

### file1.robot

```
*** Settings ***
Resource    other.robot

*** Test Cases ***
MyTest1
    do something
    Some other keywords
```